# How to get user data from Facebook Graph Api using php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get data from facebook graph API. don't know how to get. i am following some basic tutorial but getting trouble.
Below is my code in which i am trying to see the basic object items but hese are nothing. like

```
require 'facebook-sdk-2/facebook.php';
$app_apikey =   'xxxx';
$app_secret =   'xxxxxxxxxx';

 $facebook =     new Facebook($app_apikey, $app_secret);
 var_dump($facebook); //returns object items

 var_dump($facebook->getUser()); //returns null
```

i would like further to get user events moreover.

RESULTS

```
  var_dump($facebook); //returns object items
object(Facebook)[1]
  protected 'sharedSessionID' => null
  protected 'appId' => string '2' (length=1)
  protected 'appSecret' => string '2' (length=1)
  protected 'user' => null
  protected 'signedRequest' => null
  protected 'state' => null
  protected 'accessToken' => null
  protected 'fileUploadSupport' => boolean false
  protected 'trustForwarded' => boolean false

var_dump($facebook->getUser()); //returns null 
int 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't login into application, yet.